# Как разместить элементы управления, перекрывающие друг друга?

Tags: android, android-layout

Например, расположена кнопка внутри layout, а поверх неё расположен TextView.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это делается с помощью [наложения](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html) элементов в [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html).

```
<FrameLayout >
    <Button />
    <TextView />
</FrameLayout>
```